# Django many to many relationship with join table-specific fields

Tags: django, orm, django-models, many-to-many

I am migrating my app to Django and using their built-in ORM instead of writing SQL queries. The problem I am having is with one of my many to many relationships. I have the following models:

```
class Orgs(models.Model):
    org = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    org_hood = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Members(models.Model):
    member_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    is_self_managed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    orgs = models.ManyToManyField(Orgs, null=True)
```

There are many Orgs and many Members. A member can be part of many Orgs and an Org can have many members. Each member has a balance ($0.00) associated to the Org they are a part of. For example:

```
member1 is in Org1 with a balance of $3.85
member1 is in Org2 with a balance of $2.00
member2 is in Org1 with a balance of $0.85
```

I can't figure out how to define this balance field. When I wasn't using the ORM, I manually created the join table and defined these fields I needed right in the join table.

Comment: FYI, since you're new to Django, standard practice is for models to be singular: `Org` and `Member`. Up to you, of course...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) argument to `ManyToManyField` you can explicitly define the join table and put the balance field there.

```
class Orgs(models.Model):
    ...
    members = ManyToManyField(Members, through='Membership')

class Members(models.Model):
    ...

class Membership(models.Model)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Orgs)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Members)
    balance = models.DecimalField()  # or whatever your field type is
```